# MySQL - ExecuteScalar is returning byte[]

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to fetch HTML content which is in the form of text in database. To get it, I am using `ExecuteScalar` as follows:

```
query = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',field1, field2) FROM table_name WHERE id = 123";
Comm.CommandText = query;
return Comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

But, instead of HTML content in string form, I am getting `"System.Byte[]"`.

We have been using `ExecuteScalar` and always converted the returned object to required datatype. But don't know why we’re getting `byte[]` in this case.

Comment: My guess is that your query is returning more than one record.  What happens when you run that query directly against your MySQL instance?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Where id = 123 should make sure that its one record only. And direct query giving me proper result.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thats fine, but the problem here is its returning System.Byte[] as a string. Means, I am getting the return value as Byte[], while I am expecting a string value returned from database.

Comment: What are the column types of field1, field2 (or the real columns you’re querying)? Is any BLOB, TINYBLOB, BINARY(n) etc?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger well, you gave a hint. Although BLOB, TINYBLOB, BINARY(n) are not in the result. But I guess  CONCAT_WS() here may be causing the trouble.

Comment: What are the types of the columns you’re passing as arguments to CONCAT_WS?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Its longtext.

Comment: I'm not able to repro this with `LONGTEXT` columns. What is your connection string (with log in details redacted)?

Comment: connectionString="Database='SomeDB';Data Source='DS'; User Id='uid';Password='psw';Connection Timeout =5; Pooling=false;"

Comment: @BradleyGrainger IDK why but its working when I am not using CONCAT_WS, and fetching the columns individually and then filling it in a datatable. Then fetching the row and merging all of its column as string. This is the workaround I got as of now.